# Python interpreting JSON values

Tags: python, json

I'm working with some Google Custom Search Engine queries and getting the results back in JSON format via Python script. One of the fields that I'm interested in is the totalResults field, which will tell me how many hits there are in the search and I will need to do multiple queries as Google only returns 10 hits at a time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json
import re

r=requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY&cx=MY_APP_ID&q=MY_QUERY&alt=json",)

myjson=r.json()

print myjson["searchInformation"]["totalResults"]

for hit in myjson["items"]:
        date=re.match('\w+ \d+\, \d+',hit["snippet"])
        print str(date.group())+" "+hit["formattedUrl"]
```

When I get my search results back

```
u'searchInformation': {u'formattedSearchTime': u'0.26',
                    u'formattedTotalResults': u'489',
                    u'searchTime': 0.25836300000000001,
                    u'totalResults': u'489'},
```

I want Python to return the value of totalResults:

```
print myjson["searchInformation"]["totalResults"]
```

But rather than returning 489, Python is returning 21 which seems to be the sum of the integers in the totalResults field. So how to grab the value of this field as it is?

Comment: Added more information in the edit, accidentally submitted the question before I was done asking it.

Comment: Add `print r.text`, `print myjson`, and `print myjson["searchInformation"]` to see what Google is returning.

Comment: I know what Google is returning, I'd like to know why Python is summing the numbers in the totalResults field rather than returning the stored value.

Comment: If you know what Google is returning, then please create a short, complete, standalone program that demonstrates the error.  Please copy-paste that entire short program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: I pasted my entire script in my question. Notnsure what else what you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking for a verifiable example. See [mcve] for more information. I can't verify your example, because you have (correctly) removed your credentials. One way that you can create a short verifiable example by printing `r.content`, removing the unnecessary bits, and save that to a script that uses `json.loads()` against that content. Then, when you have the smallest version of that script that still fails, copy-paste that into your question.

Comment: I did that. My entire script and the applicable output from my Google query. It was sufficient for TheGreatContini to work with, not sure why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> server_response = '{"searchInformation": {"formattedSearchTime": "0.26", "formattedTotalResults": "489", "searchTime": 0.25836300000000001, "totalResults": "489"} }'
>>> myjson = json.loads(server_response)
>>> print myjson["searchInformation"]["totalResults"]
489
```

Maybe that will help you debug the problems you are having.